# Java cast interface to class

Tags: java, class, interface, casting

I have a question about interface and class implementing interface.

This is my code:

```
interface iMyInterface {
    public iMethod1();
}

public class cMyClass implements iMyInterface {
    public iMethod1() {
        // some code
    }
    protected iMethod2() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

I would like to create an instance of `iMyInterface` as this :

```
iMyInterface i = new cMyClass();
i.iMethod1();
```

It's ok, but how can I call `iMethod2()` from my interface instance? Is this working and safe:

```
((cMyClass)i).iMethod2();
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that will work (if you change the declaration of `cMyClass` to implement `iMyInterface`) and it's safe so long as the reference really *does* refer to an instance of `cMyClass`.

However, it's a generally bad idea. The whole point of using an interface is to be able to work with *any* implementation - it's to separate the abstraction from the implementation. If you're then going to require a specific implementation, you might as well make the type of `i` just `cMyClass` to start with.

So suppose instead of calling the `cMyClass` constructor yourself, you receive a method parameter of type `iMyInterface` - it's a bad idea to cast to `cMyClass` at that point, as it could be a *different* implementation of the interface.

(On a separate note, it's a good idea to start following Java naming conventions, which state that classes and interfaces should be Pascal-cased - so ditch the `c` and `i` prefixes.)

Comment: I think that, if he's going to cast, he should verify the cast with `instanceof`, to be on the safe side.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Unless the desired failure mode is an ClassCastException anyway, of course, in which case an unconditional cast is fine.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks, I'm using it now including Method2 in interface. Sorry I forgot to add **implements iMyInterface** in my sample.

Answer (score 0):

It will work (provided that cMyClass implements iMyInterface and you are in scope of *protected* modifier) but that is not the correct OO approch.

If you want to use iMethod2 consider:

- adding it to the interface
- create another interface containing that method
- Use `cMyClass myClass = new cMyClass();`

Comment: Thanks, I add Method2 in my interface.

Comment: You actually want to restrict your instance type to the smallest reasonable interface like ```List<String> l = new ArrayList<>() ;``` if you want to use arraylist specific methods Widen your variable type.

Answer (score 0):

There is some another alternative to cast Interface to a class. Here is example how.

```
interface iMyInterface {
   void iMethod1();
}

public class cMyClass implements iMyInterface {

private iMyInterface myInterface;

public cMyClass() {
    myInterface = this;
}

public void iMethod1(){
    System.out.println("Print from cMyClass iMethod1()");
}

protected void iMethod2() {
    System.out.println("Print from cMyClass iMethod2()");
}

/**
 * Getter so we can access to the interface methods.
 * @return
 */
public iMyInterface getMyInterface() {
    return myInterface;
}
}
```

And to get values from your interface, here is the code example.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    cMyClass myClass = new cMyClass();
    myClass.getMyInterface().iMethod1();
    myClass.iMethod2();
}
}
```

Output:

Print from cMyClass iMethod1()

Print from cMyClass iMethod2()

I think this is a good example how you can separate interface code from the class code. Just create instance of the interface and every method use through getter with that interface.

Comment: I know 4 years. But your answer does nothing. Calling the interface methods on the class itself is fine. There is no convention I know that tells you to separate them. And if you really want to you can cast implicitly : ```iMyInterface i = classInstance; ``` you need no method for this.