# Casting between Interfaces and Classes

Tags: java, interface

Yesterday I just started learning interfaces and have been doing some simple examples, I noticed that I have had lots of trouble understanding casting between classes and interfaces so I read [Java Cast Interface to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875513/java-cast-interface-to-class) as well as [Interfaces Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

However when my book gave a small review question at the bottom, I noticed that I still didn't really understand completely, and the book I bought doesent have solutions. The following is the question ( I gave my attempt and reasoning which is probably wrong for some, so any help is good!)

> Suppose the class Sandwich implements the Edible interface, and you
>   are given the variable declarations

```
Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();

Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30); 

Edible e = null;
```

> Which of the following assignment statements are legal?

1. `e = sub;`

   Since the Sandwich class implements the interface `Edible`, this is no     problem. We can say `e = sub` with no issues. **It Works**
2. `sub = e;`

   Since we are trying to change our object `sub` in the `Sandwitch` class to an `interface` type, we can't do this without casting. **It won't work**
3. `sub = (Sandwich) e`

   **Works**! This fixes our old problem
4. `sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;`

   I have no clue.. but it should **work?** `cerealBox` is a `Rectangle` so with `(Sandwich)` we convert it to `sub`, which is part of `Sandwich`
5. `e =cerealBox;`

   Don't think so. `Rectangle` isn't implemented the `Edible` interface so it **shouldnt work**
6. `e = (Edible) cerealBox;`

   Should **work** now. (Edible) acts as if it implements the interface.
7. `e = (Rectangle) cerealBox;`

   **Not sure**. I don't think this will work, I mean `cerealBox` is of type Rectangle, why are we making it a `rectangle` again?
8. `e = (Rectangle) null;`

   **Not sure at all**

Comment: Why won't you try it yourself? The compiler will tell you the answer.

Comment: I'm not interested in the answer. I'd like to know why

Comment: But you are writing the question as if you didn't try and want to know if your answers are right or wrong. I suggest that you [edit] it and add something like "I thought this would work, but it doesn't. Why?". You answer to 8, for example, doesn't show that you're requesting reasoning.

Comment: *casting doesn't convert anything*, it's you telling the compiler you know what the right type is and the compiler should shut up and make it work. if you're wrong you get an error at run time.

Comment: Please add the declarations of `Sandwich`, `Rectangle` and `Edible` into the question, so that the question is complete without referring to an external page. (Also fix the spelling of `Sandwich` where it's wrong :) )

Comment: I'm assuming a `Rectangle` is not `Edible`. The compiler won't have that.

Comment: To answer all those questions you need additional information: Is `Rectangle` a superclass of `Sandwich`?  Is `Sandwich` a superclass of `Rectangle`? Does `Rectangle` implement `Edible`. Probably the answer to all of those is "no", but without this information it's impossible to answer all questions.

Comment: I'm not on my laptop right now but when I can ill add details. From what I remember I did indeed type the whole question from the textbook. I haven't learned inheritance yet by the way, the chapter before was explaining when yo use static methods and passing by value, as well as wrapping up arrays and arraylists

Comment: OP is using an example from a textbook and appears to have stated the full question as worded. It is safe to assume there are no gotchas or dumb tricks like making Edible an empty interface (which would change the answer to #6), and that there is no weird inheritance play going on.

Comment: BTW: the answer to #6 could be different, if `Rectangle` is `final`.

Comment: @fabian Am I doing something wrong? I can't get `final` to create a compiler error. [Here's the test.](https://ideone.com/0xYndq)

Comment: @4castle I didn't mean adding the `final` modifier to the variable. I meant: add it to the `Rectangle` class: https://ideone.com/4ERKox

Comment: Ok, I'm back. I actually did indeed write the question in its full. Gonna take a look at the answers below. Thanks all. Looks like this question is much more complex than I though, it was just a small self check at the bottom of the page lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to understand is that every object has one concrete class. It "is" an instance of that class, and it "is" an instance of every class that class inherits, **all at the same time**.  Not only that but it "is" an instance of every *interface* any of those classes inherit, **all at the same time**.

So, assuming:

```
 class Animal
 class Mammal extends Animal implements Suckler
 class Dog extends Mammal implements Woofer
```

... if I create a `new Dog()` then that object "is" an `Object` (because all objects inherit `Object`), an `Animal`, a `Mammal`, a `Suckler`, a `Dog` and a `Woofer`, **all at the same time**.

However, a *variable* is not the same thing as an object. A variable points at an object, and a variable has a type. The type must be compatible with the object assigned, but that's all.

So:

```
Suckler s = new Dog();
```

works, but from that moment on, all the compiler knows about the object **via the `s` variable** is that it's a `Suckler`. It doesn't know it's a dog; it doesn't know it's a mammal. So we cannot then go:

```
Dog d = s;
```

... because the compiler can't guarantee that the variable pointed to by `s` is a `Dog`.

The type of the *variable* cannot ever be changed. `s` has type `Suckler` for the whole of its lifetime, no matter what. We could assign a `Sheep` or a `Pig` to `s`, but we won't be able to *do anything* to those objects except operations that are part of the `Suckler` definition.

---

I'm going to assume that the various classes and interfaces are defined like this:

```
 public interface Edible {
     ...
 }

 public class Sandwich implements Edible {
     ...
 }

 public class Rectangle {  // note, does not implement or extend anything
                           // (except Object)
     ...
 }
```

So:

```
Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();
Edible e = null;
e = sub;
```

This is fine. `sub` is a `Sandwich`, and `Sandwich` is a kind of `Edible`.

---

```
Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();
Edible e = null;
sub = e;
```

This won't compile. `e` is an `Edible`, but there could be any number of classes that implement `Edible`, as well as `Sandwich`. `sub` has to be a `Sandwich` and since the compiler can't be sure that `e` is a sandwich, it will refuse to compile.

---

```
Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();
Edible e = null;
sub = (Sandwich) e;
```

This works. As you've correctly worked out, the cast tells the compiler "OK, you can't be sure that `e` is a `Sandwich`, but as the coder, I'm telling you it is.

If you did this, and at runtime `e` was actually an `Apple implements Edible`, and not a `Sandwich`, the JRE would throw a `ClassCastException`. It's your job to make sure this doesn't happen -- avoiding casting is the best way to do this.

---

```
Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();
Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30); 
sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;
```

... will refuse to compile. `Sandwich` and `Rectangle` are not related to one another. The compiler knows that no `Sandwich` is also a `Rectangle`, so it refuses to compile.

The variable `sub` must always point to a `Sandwich`, and `cerealBox` must always point to a `Rectangle`. The only way a `Rectangle` could be a `Sandwich` is if `Rectangle` inherited `Sandwich`, or vice versa. Since neither of these is the case, it won't compile.

This is assuming the declarations above. It's possible for a class to implement multiple interfaces, so if it was `public class Sandwich implements Edible, Rectangle {...}`, this code would work.

---

```
Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30); 
Edible e = null;
e = cerealBox;
```

... will not compile. A `Rectangle` is not an `Edible`.

---

```
Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30); 
Edible e = null;
e = (Edible) cerealBox;
```

.. at first glance, you might think will not compile. A `Rectangle` is not an `Edible`, and you can't tell the compiler it is. However the compiler can't guarantee that there isn't a class like this:

```
public class Flapjack extends Rectangle implements Edible { ... }
```

A `Flapjack` would be a kind of `Rectangle` that is also an `Edible`, and since the compiler isn't clever enough to know that `cerealBox` is not a `Flapjack`, it must compile (it will fail in runtime).

A *really clever* compiler might be able to analyse the program logic to see that `cerealBox` has been initialised as `new Rectangle()`, and that there has been no opportunity for that to change at runtime. But the Java standard does not have that kind of sophisticated static analysis.

The writer of `Rectangle` could ensure that `Square` can't exist, by defining it as `public final class Rectangle` -- the `final` keyword forbids subclasses.

---

```
Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30); 
Edible e = null;
e = (Rectangle) cerealBox;
```

... won't compile. `e` is still an `Edible`. You can't assign a `Rectangle` to it, because `Edible` and `Rectangle` are not related.

---

```
Edible e = null;
e = (Rectangle) null;
```

Casting null to a `Rectangle` is fine, however `e` is an `Edible`, and you can't assign a `Rectangle` to an `Edible`, since they are unrelated types.

Comment: I'm confused about sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;, The (Sandwich) tells the compiler "Hey make cerealBox(a rectangle) into of the Sandwitch type." sub is also of type sandwich. So whats the issue?

Comment: I guess my logic above could apply to e = (Edible) cerealBox; as well.. edit : OOPS apparently it does compile according to the first comment

Comment: It's not that "*The compiler knows that no `Sandwich` is also a `Rectangle`*". It's that the compiler knows that no class could extend both `Sandwich` and `Rectangle`, and it knows that `Rectangle` doesn't extend `Sandwich`. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so it can assume the relationship is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, gave this correct answer as its more detailed. Great answers though

Answer (score 4):

#4, 6, 7, & 8 are the ones you need help on. They are all about casting. A cast is only legal if the origin type and the destination type potentially have a relationship through inheritance. A variable assignment is legal only if the right-hand side has the same type or a subtype of the left-hand side.

### #4 `sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;`

Both sides are of type `Sandwich` after the cast, however `(Sandwich) cerealBox` is an illegal cast. **This will not work**. The reason this is an illegal cast is because casting cannot happen between classes that are on different inheritance branches. There is no situation where a `Rectangle` could be a `Sandwich`, so this is a compiler error.

### #6 `e = (Edible) cerealBox;`

This is different from #4 because it is an interface. It is legal, but may throw a runtime error. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21812289/5743988) for a good explanation. At compile-time, there's no way to know if `cerealBox` might actually be a subtype of `Rectangle` that is `Edible`. **This will work.** If `Rectangle` was `final`, this would not work.

### #7 `e = (Rectangle) cerealBox;`

It's legal to cast a variable to the same type. It is not legal to assign a `Rectangle` to a variable of type `Edible`. `Rectangle` does not implement `Edible`. **This will not work.**

### #8 `e = (Rectangle) null;`

It's legal to cast `null` to any type. **This will not work** though because `Rectangle` does not implement `Edible`.

Comment: "different inheritance chains",not exactly too sure what this means (inheritance is ch 11)  
I'm confused about sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;, The (Sandwich) tells the compiler "Hey make cerealBox(a rectangle) into of the Sandwitch type." sub is also of type sandwich. So whats the issue?

Comment: I guess my logic above could apply to e = (Edible) cerealBox; as well.. (Which do not work as stated by you and the person below)

Comment: #6 will work, but #4 will not. #4 doesn't compile because a class can only have one superclass. If `Rectangle` could be cast to a `Sandwich`, it would be because `Rectangle extends Sandwich` somehow. The compiler is able to make assumptions about `cerealBox` based on the class definition of `Rectangle`, so the cast fails at compile-time. #4 will make more sense once you learn about inheritance.

Comment: Ok I will forget about 6 for now. Is the basic idea of 4 the following : Even though sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox;, has both sides of type Sandwich, cerealBox which is originally a rectangle does not implement Rectangle. THUS we have two requirements. The class we are referring to must implement Rectangle ALSO we use a cast conversion like sub = (Sandwich) cerealBox. I.E To solve this we do public class Sandwich implements Rectangle

Comment: I keep seeing this extend keyword everywhere, but haven't even touched inheritance. This is making things hard for me to understand, not sure why  my book ordered interfaces first :(

Comment: The `implements` keyword is used for inheritance from interfaces, and the `extends` keyword is used for inheritance from classes. To cast one class to another class, they must inherit from one another in some way, so the solution would be `Sandwich extends Rectangle` or `Rectangle extends Sandwich` in order for #4 to work.

Comment: Got it. I think it makes sense. Thanks alot :)

Comment: I suggest you read ahead a bit more before asking questions on SE. The book is likely to make all this clear in its own time.

Comment: Okay, I do agree its confusing. After i learn inhertiance I will come back to this question. Hopefully it will be more clear

Comment: By the way what does subclass mean? I keep hearing it

Comment: A subclass is a class which extends another class. For example, all classes are a subclass of the [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class.